# apt-get remove indicator-bluetooth removes lot of packages

Tags: apt, indicator

I want to remove indicator-bluetooth, but it shows me, that all will be removed?

```
  indicator-bluetooth ubuntu-desktop unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon webaccounts-extension-common
  xul-ext-webaccounts
```

How can I remove just Bluetooth indicator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Instead of this you can disable it.

Open ***System Settings* → *Bluetooth***: Turn it off there inc. not showing in menu bar.

For reference, see: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2280125

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the above answer does not solve the problem, namely on Ubuntu 16.04.3 disabling bluetooth via System Settings (including the option to not show in the menu bar) does not prevent the indicator-bluetooth process from starting up and thus wasting the precious memory and other resources.

The only way to stop it is to disable access to its executable file like this:

`$ sudo chmod 0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/indicator-bluetooth/indicator-bluetooth-service`

I show the 32bit architecture path in the above example, because I assume you want to do this on a 32bit machine, just like I did on an old Acer Aspire One netbook with only 2GB RAM and Intel Atom 1.66GHz CPU, so every kilobyte of memory is important, let alone thirty or so MEGABYTES that the bluetooth indicator was stealing....